# Angular + SignalR - how to share SignalR connection between component (each component is in a separated tab)

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr

I've created a service to handle SignalR connection:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {

  constructor(private logMessageService: LogMessageService) { }
  public connection: signalR.HubConnection;
  public RecievedObject;
  public RecievedObjectEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
  // public connectionId: string;
  public signalRClientId: Guid = Guid.newGuid();
  public startConnection = () => {
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${g.magb1Url}hub/public`)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();
    this.connection.start().then(() => {
      console.log('connected');
      this.connection
        .invoke('Register', this.signalRClientId)
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      this.connection.on('messageReceived', (object: any) => {
        this.RecievedObjectEmitter.emit(object);
        this.RecievedObject = object;
      });
      this.logMessageService.Init(this.signalRClientId);

    });
    return this.connection;
  }
}
```

And in the home page, I'm starting the connection, I am sending a message to a specific client and the main issue is when I open another component inside a new browser tab, the variable "RecievedObject" in the service is coming as undefined.

Comment: If you open another tab then i would assume its a new instance. what happen if you have both tabs open and then sends the data to the client. do they both receive it same time ?

Comment: No, I tried to open both tabs and send a message to the client, but the message didn't receive because I wasn't able to share the connection  neither the client Id @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen

Comment: ahh yeah i see you use a guid generation for the id. If you want to share the data a cross tabs you could use localstorage for that as a simple solution.

Comment: ok, I got you, thanks for the help.